# Exclude Directories when using Pstorm in PhpStorm

Tags: python, phpstorm

I was wondering if anyone knew a code fix to the pstorm python script where you could exclude directories from being indexed in a directory when you open it from the command line.

I know this is not currently a feature in the IDE but maybe there is a work around someone knows of.

Thanks

Comment: If you know a directory name, you can exclude it globally in the IDE `Settings` | `File Types` | `Ignore Files and Folders`. When you open a project from the command line, the directory will not be shown and indexed. There is no way to control it from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Settings` | `File Types` | `Ignore Files and Folders` to exclude directories by name or pattern.